# How can I share same components between multiple projects?

Tags: reactjs

I have 8 react projects in same folder. 
Project1,
Project2,
Project3,
...

I need to have also folder that contains all reusable components that i can later import in any of those react projects. So, I want to be aple to import components from new components folder or somehow link that files to my react projects. How can I do that but without makin npm repo and using a Bit. 
I cant find online someones code that I could use for this.

Comment: you can create shared repo/package of your shared components and add this as dependency in projects where you want to use them.

Comment: You can use a bundler like Webpack or Rollup to package all your components into a single distribution file and import this file in all your projects.